# Converting SQL query to DAX in Power Bi to get a single value from table

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have a simple `SQL` query that i want to convert it to `DAX` so that i can use it in `Power BI` to create a new measure.
This is the query :

```
SELECT [Value] FROM Core.tblConfigurations WHERE [Key] = 'ReportMinBase'
```

Here is the table that i want to execute this query on it :

[image: Table Preview]

I want the result of this `DAX` query to be just "50" in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    YourMeasure =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( TableName[Value] ), TableName[Key] = "ReportMinBase" )
```

The Key "ReportMinBase" is the Filter applied to retrieve the Value using the `CALCULATE` function.
Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax for `CALCULATE` function and its usage.